# Scroll autosize div between two divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys I'm making a website for a customer.
And the basic layout should me like this : http://jsfiddle.net/t6EKv/469/

The problem is I need the middle div to scroll trough the content and the header and footer should always stay visible.

To make this a little bit more complicated I am going to support monitor widths greater or equal then 1280px. Since buttons and text will be shown in the header and footer (positioned absolute), the page in its entirety should be able to scroll on the y axis for smaller screen withs. The scrolling part is not part of the question, but it just means that I cant use `postion:fixed;` on any of the 3 divs.

I got this working perfectly in chrome, but as soon as I checked firefox and IE it failed miserably. Firefox collapses the content div and shows the actual content on a higher z-index than the header. IE will for some reason not show my entire content.

I put the basics of my current code in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9JMm2. But even here it seems buggier than it does in my version of chrome.

Can anybody help out?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/SSHe6/

Answer (score 0):

Use "absolute", while for content use "overflow:auto"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div.header { position:absolute; top:0em; height:1em; background-color:red; white-space:nowrap; min-width:640px;}
            div.content { position:absolute; top:1em; bottom:1em; overflow:auto; background-color:green;}
            div.footer { position:absolute; bottom:0em; height:1em; background-color:yellow;white-space:nowrap;min-width:640px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class='header'> this is the header </div>

        <div class='content'> 
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
            this is the content this is the content this is the content  
         </div>

        <div class='footer'> this is the footer </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will check it out tomorrow, I am afraid it will ruin my overflow-x scenario. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I cant seem to get it to work with the log in button in place. Plus it gives me a scrollbar for the entire page.

Comment: which log button?  where should it be?  Using FireFox (linux) I had no global scrollbar.  what browser do you use?  (If ms-explorrer - what version of it?)